# Creating a movable sql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, file, local

So I'm working on a project that is just a simple dictionary program. It uses C++ and will fetch data such as definitions from a sql database. I'm very new to sql and so my question is, is it possible to create a database file with all of the words and definitions on it and that would essentially act as my sql database and then I would use sql commands to access that file.

The reason I ask this is because if I want to be able to send this program to a friend, and not have it running over the internet, he would obviously need the file with all the definitions for it to work. If anyone could show me how one could do this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may get closed as too broad/opinionated as there are many options available.  But, consider SQLite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite

Comment: Or just swap `.sql` files around.

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are programmers in the world. Make an attempt, and then come back when you have problems with the specific attempt.

Comment: sqlite all the way. https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

Answer (score 0):

This sounds pretty straightforward. Create a database, create a dictionary table with all your words and definitions, backup the database, send your buddy the backup file. Your app/program should have a db connection string that can read words/definitions from the table.

Comment: ok thank you, do you happen to know the syntax for the db connection string? Is at simple as having "USE <database_name>;" in the .sql file?

Comment: If you both restore the db with the same database name that is currently used in the connection string, you should not have any issues.

Comment: awesome, thanks. And this question is not really related to the main question, but do you happen to know an easy way of parsing through an  online dictionary source and putting the words and definitions into a table in the .sql file, just so I don't have to type every word and definition into the table?

Answer (score -1):

Install Genesis (or The Food Processor) on the new machine. (If you are using your own instance of SQL Server this isn't needed)
On old machine, Backup the database.
Move the physical file (*.bak) to the new machine.
On the new machine, Restore the database.
  -->the steps on this document describe backup and restore.

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL. OP's not using Microsoft's SQL Server.